# GDB Visual Core Dump Analysis

Tags: software-development, debugging

Is there a tool that allows me to input a core dump and it's associated binary and then inspect values in a GUI, visually (something like Visual Studio's debugger, just not live)?

I'm having a bit of a hard time with GDB and would love to look at it in a Visual Debugger.

I can use either Linux or Windows 7 do run that tool.

The only features I need is to be able to see all the local variables from the stack trace and see the variable values. I need to be able to drill down into specific classes and follow linked lists. I have all the source code available.

Comment: Is the core dump produced on the same platform you'll be using the debugger on (because your application is cross-platform), or on a specific platform? What CPU type, executable format, etc.?

Comment: @Gilles It is an x86 32-bit QNX Neutrino 6.4.1 core dump for an ELF binary developed on a Windows 7 64-bit platform and cross-compiled to QNX. I can debug on QNX, Linux, or Windows. Windows would probably be the easiest, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux, you will do just fine with [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org/).

Just give it the path to your executable, and away you go.

> Features
>
> •Inspection of variable values in a tree structure.
>
> •Direct member: For certain compound data types the most important
>   member values are displayed next to the variable name, so that it is
>   not necessary to expand the subtree of that variable in order to see
>   the member value. For example, you don't need to go into a variable of
>   type QString if you want to see the string that the variable holds.
>   (BTW, this is of course not hardcoded, but can be extended to new
>   types.) KDbg can even display Qt's QString values, which are Unicode
>   strings.
>
> •Debugger at your finger tips: The basic debugger functions (step,
>   next, run, finish, until, set/clear/enable/disable breakpoint) are
>   bound to function keys F5 through F10. Quick and easy.
>
> •Of course, lots of other basic functions: View source code, search
>   text, set program arguments and environment variables, display
>   arbitrary expressions. Everything you need to debug a program!
>
> •Debugging of core dumps, attaching to running processes is possible.
>
> •Conditional breakpoints.

[image]

---

Another good option is the [Data Diaply Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), known as DDD, which has the additional feature of visually displaying data structures and their linkages,
[image]

as well as allowing you to plot data:
[image]

Also, search the DDD page for "related resources", to find a few more which I was not aware of.

Comment: Just curious - which did you go for?