# Gratis, portable GDB GUI for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, portable

As the title says, I am looking for a:

- Gratis
- portable
- GDB GUI
- for Windows

I don't actually have a feature wish list; it's just that some of the junior engineers have only ever known GUI-based programs and are having difficulties coming to grips with GDB.

We are not allowed to install software, so it has to be portable. Something like [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org/) would be perfect, but I can't find a portable Windows version.

BTw, it must be a Windows desktop program (.EXE, Java, Python, etc). We are not allowed to use [gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui), the answer to [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/decent-gui-for-gdb), because it runs in the browser.

This [related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/gdb-visual-core-dump-analysis) has no answers yet (I am about to answer with KDbg, but that won't help me).

Any ideas? Google is not my friend today :-(

Comment: Not allowed to install software AND not allowed to run software in the browser?! Are you folks allowed to type with your hands, or do you have to poke at the keys with a pen you hold between your teeth?

Comment: I guess you never worked a defence project? We just upgraded to Windows 7 last year. I could tell you more, but then I would have to ...

Comment: Have you ever tried [Qt Creator](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/4.15/4.15.0/installer_source/windows_x64/qtcreator.7z)?

Comment: I think that we would prefer a link to a website, so that we can see what we are downloading, not juts a link to *.7z file. Do you mean https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools ? Also, can you explain how that answers the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has a [portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable). You just need to config the path to the GDB executable and install required extensions

See [Windows debugging with GDB](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_windows-debugging-with-gdb) for more information

Answer (score 0):

A gdb GUI is essentially just an IDE. There are many portable IDEs around there. One of them is the famous [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) which has [nosetup](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/)/[portable](https://www.fosshub.com/Code-Blocks.html) releases and even includes a GCC compiler inside in case you need

[Debugging with Code::Blocks](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks)

> ### Debugger:
>
> - Interfaces GNU GDB
> - Also supports MS CDB (not fully featured)
> - Full breakpoints support:
>
>   - Code breakpoints
>   - Data breakpoints (read, write and read/write)
>   - Breakpoint conditions (break only when an expression is true)
>   - Breakpoint ignore counts (break only after certain number of hits)
> - Display local function symbols and arguments
> - User-defined watches (support for watching user-defined types through scripting)
> - Call stack
> - Disassembly
> - Custom memory dump
> - Switch between threads
> - View CPU registers
>
> **[Code::Blocks / Features](https://www.codeblocks.org/features/)**